# Come up with polynomial algorithm

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

Given n checks, each of arbitrary (integer) monetary value, decide if the checks can be partitioned into two parts that have the same monetary value.

I'm beyond mind blown on how to solve this.  Is there an algorithm to solve this in polynomial time or is this NP-Complete?

Comment: may be this question is better placed in [programming puzzle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) or [puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @yaitloutou I think the question is much more on-topic here than in puzzling or programming puzzle.  At most, maybe it should be posted to cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user31264 thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's an NP complete problem. It's a variation of [the subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was puzzled on this for so long. Curious what if I had N checks of two different values.  For example value X and value Y.  Then would any algorithm for this be NP complete?

Comment: For two different values you can solve simple Diophantine equation. In general case there are pseudo-polynomial algorithms using dynamic programming.

Comment: You are wrong, this is can be done with a  polynomial complexity using dynamic programming.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Sorry you're wrong. This is called a "weakly NP complete problem." It can be solved by a dynamic program in time proportional to the magnitude of the numbers. If the numbers aren't limited range, this requires time exponential in the size of the inputs.

Comment: Yeah, you are right I didn't know about "weakly NP complete problem" tell know, i thought knapsack problem is not an NP-complete problem, well sorry about calling you're solution wrong!

Comment: If only two possible values exist for the N checks how would you reduce this to prove it's NP-complete? I was able to do a polynomial time reduction for it having any values but with two I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can solve this in O(n*sum/2) using dynamic programming, first sum up all checks into a varaibel sum, then you can perform dp on the checks values (either take it or leave it or take it) and check at the end if that sum is equal to s/2.

Comment: Still, this isn't P because `sum` grows with `n`. Since the algorithm either takes or leaves a check, for every check, there is exponential complexity.